# Integral over some measure is the same as integrating over the measure of the preimages of some intervals

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, measurable-functions

Sorry for the somewhat confusing question. I'm currently working on this problem:

> Let ($\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mu$) be a σ-finite measure space and $f: \Omega \rightarrow \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ with $\overline{\mathbb{R}} = \mathbb{R} \cup \{\pm \infty\}$ non-negative and measurable function. Then $$\int_\Omega f d\mu = \int_0^\infty\mu(\{f \geq t\})dt$$ where $\{f \geq t\} = \{x \in \Omega : f(x) \geq t\}$

I already figured it out for simple functions and are now trying to prove the general case. I've got so far: Let $(\varphi_k) \nearrow f$ with $(\varphi_k) = \sum_{i=1}^{n^{(k)}} a_i^{(k)} \chi_{A_i^{(k)}}$

Then: $$\int_\Omega f d\mu = \int \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \varphi_k d\mu = \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \int \varphi_k d\mu = \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^\infty\mu(\{\varphi_k \geq t\})dt$$

Now define $t_0 := \sum_{i=1}^{n^{(k)}} a_i^{(k)} = \max_{x \in \Omega} (\varphi_k(x))$

$\varphi_k$ definitely doesn't get bigger than $t_0$ and only "reaches" $t_0$ if $x \in \bigcup_{i = 1}^n A_i^{(k)}$. Therefore

$$\int_0^\infty\mu(\{\varphi_k \geq t\})dt = \int_0^{t_0} \mu(\bigcup_{i = 1}^n A_i^{(k)}) dt = t_0 \mu(\Omega)$$ since we can assume without loss of generality that $\bigcup_{i = 1}^n A_i^{(k)} = \Omega$.

But I don't really see where to from here. Anyone have a clue? Especially why the σ-finity is necessary.

Comment: @AI.G. Yes, you're right. My mistake! You should probably just use some maximum $a_i^{(k)}$ but that doesn't really change a whole lot in the argumentation as far as I can see.

Comment: @AI.G. I think I've figured it out: $\mu(\{f \geq\ t\}) - \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \mu(\{\varphi_k \geq t \}) = \mu(\{f \geq t\} \setminus \{\varphi_k \geq t\})$ and this set converges to zero since $\varphi_k$ converges piecewiese and monotonic to f. Was this also your argumentation?

Comment: Yes, but *why* does the measure of this set tend to zero, given that pointwise $\varphi_k\to f$? Can you prove it (e.g. by definition of limit)? It sounds intuitive, but the link is certainly not direct, and probably not even true in general (you still haven't used $\sigma$-finiteness!).

Comment: @A.I.G. I think I can follow your steps but I don't really see where it's going to lead. I'm not really sure how to evaluate the integral or what role the $\sigma$-finiteness plays. Do you mind giving another hint?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149937/discussion-between-al-g-and-zedssad).

Comment: Yes, I added another hint that (almost) takes you to the end. I deleted some of my comments here to clean space because they're already available in the chat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply [monotone convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem) (again) at $\overset{!}{=}$, then we're left to prove $\overset{!!}{=}$:

\begin{align}\int_\Omega f d\mu = \int \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \varphi_k d\mu &= \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \int \varphi_k d\mu\\
&= \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^\infty\mu(\{\varphi_k \geq t\})dt\\
&\overset{!}{=}\int_0^\infty\lim_{k \to \infty}\mu(\{\varphi_k \geq t\})dt\\
&\overset{!!}{=}\int_0^\infty\mu(\{f \geq t\})dt\\
\end{align}

Proving $\overset{!!}=$ is really fun, and I'd spare any details for now if you'd like to try it yourself. It is based both on $(\varphi_k) \nearrow f$ and on the property you wondered how to use.

To justify monotone convergence at $\overset{!}{=}$, ensure that for each $t\in\mathbb R^+$, $g_t(k)=\mu(\{\varphi_{k}\geq t\})$

1. is non-decreasing - follows immediately from monotonicity of $\varphi_k$ and additivity of $\mu$.
2. converges (to what?). This one will follow from the $\overset{!!}=$ step (almost everywhere, which suffices for the theorem).

---

Here's a hint for $\overset{!!}=$ if you don't even know how to start:

> Compute the difference of the terms under the integrals $$\mu(\{f\geq t\})-\lim_{k\to\infty}\mu(\{\varphi_{k}\geq t\})$$ as much as possible to the form $$\lim_{k\to\infty}\mu(\textrm{some set})$$ and then look at the $f>t$ and $f=t$ cases separately.

And a bit more, should you need it:

> For a fixed $t$, show that the above limit equals $$\lim_{k\to\infty}\mu(\{f\ge t>\varphi_k\}).$$ Next, split the cases $f>t$ and $f=t$, writing the set inside as the disjoint union $$\{f>t>\varphi_k\}\cup\{f=t>\varphi_k\}.$$ Now measure both sets separately. As $k\to\infty$, show that the first set eventually vanishes. Hence you're only concerned with the second set, where you can drop the $>\varphi_k$ part (why?) and the limit as a whole, so what's left to compute is $$\int_0^\infty \mu(\{x:f(t)=x\})dt.$$

Finally,

> Is it possible for $$\int_0^\infty \mu(\{x:f(t)=x\})dt$$ to be strictly positive? If yes, that'd mean that for uncountably many $t$, the term inside was positive, i.e. $t$ would have a non-zero measure preimage $f^{-1}(t)$. If $T$ is the (uncountable) set of such $t$s, then $$\bigcup_{t\in T}f^{-1}(t)\subseteq\Omega$$ would be an uncountable disjoint union of positive-measure sets. But $\Omega$ is $\sigma$-finite, hence a contradiction (why?)!